# Blackberry XML DOM Parser Problem (getDocumentElement())

Tags: xml, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, domparser

I am trying to use XML DOM Parser on Blackberry. However i couldn't get the root element.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("abcd.xml");
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = builder.parse(is);
    Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList rootTag = root.getElementsByTagName("myRootElementName");

    Node subTag = rootTag.item(0); 
    items = subTag.getChildNodes();
```

When i debug the code above, rootTag.item(0); is returning null.

Can anybody help me please. (The same code works fine on Android).

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? #getElementsByTagName() should never return null, maybe an empty node list.

Comment: Oh, i am sorry. rootTag.item(0); is returning null.

Comment: Ok, so you got an empty node list. Maybe you should ask the Document for all elements with that tag name, and not the root element (since you'll be missing the root itself.

Comment: And getElementsByTagName() has an empty node list/vector.

Comment: Per Norman,  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `NodeList rootTag = dom.getElementsByTagName("myRootElementName");` Replace `root` with `dom`. Waiting for your responce.

Comment: Do you have any idea, why i couldn't get the root element?

Comment: AFAIK it will not work if your xml's root node is <xml>, or you may have no root node at all, have to see your xml. Otherwise what I can do is only guess....